# react native navigation experimental header button wont show up

Tags: navigation, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm new to react native, and ES6. After research about react native with redux, I decided to use NavigationExperimental. But I have some problems with NavigationExperimental and have so many questions about NavigationExperimental because there is no complete documentation about this.

One of my problems is my navigationheader button. I have this piece of code :

```
<NavigationHeader
    {...props}
    renderTitleComponent={this._renderTitleComponent} 
    renderRightComponent={props => {
          return <TouchableHighlight>
                  <Text>test</Text>
                 </TouchableHighlight>}} />
```

this code is work, the "test" is appeared at the right top of the navigationheader.
But, when I replace it with a function, the "test" is dissapeared. here is the code :

```
<NavigationHeader
    {...props}
    renderTitleComponent={this._renderTitleComponent} 
    renderRightComponent={this._renderRightComponent} />



_renderRightComponent(props) {
      return (
          <TouchableHighlight>
            <Text>test</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      );
  }
```

anything wrong with my second code?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you try using `renderRightComponent={(props) => this._renderRightComponent(props)}`

Comment: still not working...

Answer (score 0):

```
  // 右边
  _renderRightComponent(props: NavigationSceneRendererProps): React.Element<any>{
    return (
      <NavigationHeader.Title>
        右边
      </NavigationHeader.Title>
    );
  }
```